# Are JavaScript events triggered during the onepage checkout of Magento?

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento, prototypejs

I need to run some JavaScript to manipulate some fields upon checkout (auto-select a shipping option) on a Magento store.  Because each stage of the onepage checkout accordion is loaded dynamically I cannot do this on page load, and instead need to do it when the relevant stage of the accordion is reached.

Is there a JavaScript event I can hook up to in order to achieve this?  I would expect an event to be fired when the next step begins to load and then completes loading, but I can't find any documentation on it.

Does such a thing exist, or do I need to find a workaround?

Comment: I tried to achieve something similar a while ago and I couldn't find anything. What I ended up doing is copying the opcheckout.js file in my theme's skin folder and changing that one.

Comment: @SamuelComan - Yes, I've done this by overwriting the existing method to do the normal functionality as well as my own.  That's not a very clean approach though, as any updates to the theme that apply to this function won't take effect.  From my research there are no JS events fired, which is quite an oversight in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution, but it's a bit dirty.
You could 'override' Checkout.prototype.gotoSection this way :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    // Make ref to default function
    Checkout.prototype.baseGotoSection = Checkout.prototype.gotoSection;

    // "Rewrite" function
    Checkout.prototype.gotoSection = function(section, reloadProgressBlock){

        // <your code>

        // call default function
        return this.baseGotoSection(section, reloadProgressBlock);
    };

</script>
```